# Run tests from dynamic data

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to run WebdriverIO tests based on dynamic data.

So far I have something like this:

JSON file:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Item 1",
      "value": 5000
    },    {
      "name": "Item 2",
      "value": 6000
    },
    {
      "name": "Item 3",
      "value": 7000
    }
  ]
}
```

spec file

```
import * as data from './items.data.json';
describe('Desc', () => {
    data.items.forEach((item: any) => {

        // Driver runs all these first...
        // before(async () => {
        //     await MainPage.registerItem(item.name, item.value);
        // });

        // Need to have this rather than the before
        it('Set up', async () => {
            await MainPage.registerItem(item.name, item.value);
        });

        it('Should test something', async () => {
            await OtherPage.doSomething(item.name, item.value);
        });
    });
});
```

This works but the `before` does not behave as expected and an `it` is required. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If the setup should be unique for each test case, the whole `describe` should be inside the `forEach`. You should **not** be depending on the `'Set up'` "test case" running before the actual test case. Or why not just move the setup into the test case, given it's only one line?

Comment: ahhh yes of course, your recommendations are correct, all good now, thank-you

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as data from './items.data.json';

data.items.forEach((item: any) => {

describe('Desc', () => {

        // Driver runs all these first...
        // before(async () => {
        //     await MainPage.registerItem(item.name, item.value);
        // });

        // Need to have this rather than the before
        it('Set up', async () => {
            await MainPage.registerItem(item.name, item.value);
        });

        it('Should test something', async () => {
            await OtherPage.doSomething(item.name, item.value);
        });
    });
});
```

just get the forloop with describe as before executes for each describe , else use beforeEach